# Does Mahabharata contain Siddhasana?

Tags: mahabharata, siddhasana

In a Mahabharata text of Telugu language, a verse is saying that **Siva sat in Siddhasana** and playing a game of dice. It occurs in Adi Parva. But, when I read English translation, it is as follows

> "Vyasa continued, 'The woman thereupon answered, 'O Sakra, thou mayest
> know who I am and why, unfortunate that I am, I weep, if only, O chief
> of the celestials, thou comest with me as I lead the way. Thou shall
> then see what it is I weep for." Hearing these words of the lady,
> Indra followed her as she led the way. And soon he saw, not far off
> from where he was, **a handsome youth with a young lady seated on a
> throne placed on one of the peaks of Himavat and playing at dice.**
> Beholding that youth, the thief of the celestials said, 'Know,
> intelligent youth, that this universe is under my sway.' Seeing,
> however, that the person addressed was so engrossed in dice that he
> took no notice of what he said, Indra was possessed by anger and
> repeated, 'I am the lord of the universe.
>
> [[Section 199, Vaivahika Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01200.htm)

This was told by Vyasa in conversation with Drupada about previous lives of Draupadi and Pandavas.

The English translations does not contain about Siddhasana. So, it may be up to the interpretation.

But, is there any mention about Siddhasana in Mahabharata?